# Spring MVC – include CSS files in a JSP page

Tags: css, spring, jsp, include

My project's structure is :

```
webapp:
       resources:
                 css:
                     test.css WEB-INF:
       pages:
       mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
       web.xml
```

I am trying to include a .css file in my jsp.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/css/">       </mvc:resources>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Include css in jsp:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/test.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

But it doesn't work for me.I need help, please

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/test.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

or you can try just this :

```
<link href="resources/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me . I do something this:
create a folder in webapp : css , put there my css file .
change .xml :
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>

Comment: but it doesn't work for folder resourses , only for foldres in webapp

Answer (score -1):

change this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/css/">
```

to this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/">
```